# How to simplify a method with multiple if conditions based on type of base object

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Having the code below.

```
protected IHttpActionResult HandleException(Exception ex, TransactionEntry transactionEntry, bool useForBilling)
        {
            var statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            IHttpActionResult actionResult = new InternalServerActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId);

            if (ex is AccessDeniedException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                actionResult = new ForbiddenActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId);
            }

            if (ex is TaskCanceledException || ex is OperationCanceledException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadGateway;
                actionResult = new BadGatewayActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId);
            }

            if (ex is PassportFixedWidthRequestParserException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                actionResult = new BadRequestActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId, new List<string> { ex.Message });
            }

            if (ex is VendorRequestException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                actionResult = new BadRequestActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId, ((VendorRequestException)ex).ValidationErrors.ToReadOnlyFlattenCollection());
            }

            if (ex is XsdRequestValidationException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                actionResult = new BadRequestActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId, ((IErrors)ex).Errors);
            }


            if (ex is XsdResponseValidationException)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                actionResult = new InternalServerActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId, ((IErrors)ex).Errors);
            }

            Logger.Error($"{transactionEntry.TransactionId} - ERROR! {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
            LogTransactionWithNoResponseAsync(transactionEntry, (int)statusCode, useForBilling, DateTimeOffset.Now, 0);

            return actionResult;
        }
```

It looks like something minor to bother with but annoys me and worth to try for some feedback.

The concern is while adding more exception types the method will grow, I guess I'm looking some kind of Factory, any thoughts is appreciated.

Comment: I think you could use else if

Comment: Not what I'm really looking for, but I guess you avoid the consequent checks with else if

Comment: A case statement would be cleaner in my opinion but still not a factory.

Comment: Neither the title nor the code description meet the requirements for a good question because they say nothing about what the code is actually doing.

Comment: @t3chb0t I've edited the title, let me know if you have any suggestion to change and I will consider applying your thoughts.

Comment: Please look at other titles on the front page to get an idea.  First of all, there shouldn't be an actual question in the title, but the code's purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary to map types to some custom "actionResult / statusCode" object or even just a Tuple.

This doesn't really do anything other than making the method body *appear* simpler:

```
protected IHttpActionResult HandleException(Exception ex, TransactionEntry transactionEntry, bool useForBilling)
{
     var mapping = dictionary[ex.GetType()];
     Logger.Error($"{transactionEntry.TransactionId} - ERROR! {ex.GetType()}: {ex.Message}");
     LogTransactionWithNoResponseAsync(transactionEntry, (int)mapping.StatusCode, useForBilling, DateTimeOffset.Now, 0);

     return mapping.ActionResult;
}
```

Actually, to account for the variables you would need to use a Func for ActionResult.

```
 return mapping.GetActionResult(ex, transactionEntry, Request);
```

Comment: Sounds like this might be something more pretty in my case. I agree that we don't really gain any value other than hiding the noise, which is the goal of my question.

Comment: The secondary benefit is that the handler for every exception key can be tested very easily without having all of those implementations in one function.  So I would say it goes beyond noise reduction.  I've done this many times. *thumbs-up*

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a **mapping**. For a given exception type, you're deciding the StatusCode and the ActionResult.

There are many ways to achieve such a mapping. While I'm sure that everyone will have their favorite, it's important to observe that **every** **solution will inherently need to be AT LEAST as complex as the mapping itself**, i.e. you will always have to grow your code if the list of possible Exception types grows.

I think the cleanest approach is the **switch**. Essentially, the `switch` is built specifically for cases where chaining `if else` blocks gets out of hand, which is what you're facing here.

Since **C#7**, it has become possible to use a `switch` based on type. ([StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298976/is-there-a-better-alternative-than-this-to-switch-on-type/299001#299001))

```
switch(ex)
{
    case AccessDeniedException ade:
        statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        actionResult = new ForbiddenActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId);
        break;
    case VendorRequestException vre:
        statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        actionResult = new BadRequestActionResult(Request, transactionEntry.TransactionId, vre.ValidationErrors.ToReadOnlyFlattenCollection());
        break;
    default:
        //No mapped type found
        break;
}
```

The linked answer also contains examples for C#5 and C#6. It works, but the code is a bit uglier (in my opinion).

---

**Side note**

I've mentioned this in the answer, but I want to stress it again.

The **code complexity** isn't really being changed here. You'll still be required to list all types that you wish to handle, and you'll still face the same problems if you encounter an exception type that you have not mapped yet (though you can at least provide a default handling with the `switch default`).

There's no real functional difference between the `switch`, an `if else` chain (note that you should be using `else`, which you currently are not), or any other solution (dictionary? service mapping?)

You mentioned a **factory**, but I think this is unwarranted here. A factory would do nothing to simplify the core logic (which is a mapping; which you will always need to develop and maintain), but it gets wrapped in a bunch of additional logic that makes things even bigger.
Curretnly, you're only assigning two values. If your handling grows in size, where you start setting **many** parameters (which may even need to be calculated on the spot), then a factory is a bit more appropriate (but in my opinion still not the best solution).